# What are some good Nginx rate limits for WordPress websites?

Tags: security, server, nginx, server-load

Edit:

I moved this to ServerFault, who doesn't censor and harass everyone...

https://serverfault.com/questions/1157088/what-are-some-good-nginx-rate-limits-for-wordpress-websites

--

We are optimizing the default configuration for SlickStack, and looking for some good values to recommend to users for the `limit_req` and `limit_conn` settings in Nginx.

There are plenty of tutorials around the web, but the settings used are very random.

Most of the time, something like `rate=1r/s` with `burst=1 nodelay` is used for URIs like `/wp-login.php` however this seems too liberal for strong security.

There's also not much discussion about rate-limiting the entire server/website, `.php` files, and so forth.

The `limit_conn` feature is rarely mentioned, and `limit_rate` as well.

I'm hoping to start a thread about some possible settings for typical WordPress websites, with a special nod toward cloud servers or non-shared hosting environments, keeping in mind that these settings should be adjusted depending on your expected traffic levels and otherwise...

Comment: can you narrow this down to a specific concrete question? These aren't discussion threads, you need to phrase the question in such a way that a specific answer can be picked as the correct answer for all people with this question

Comment: @TomJNowell zomg an opinion based question over here, why haven't you banned this one yet? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4664/what-are-best-practices-for-configuring-a-server-for-wordpress-sites

Comment: This one has survived 13 years! https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9402/what-are-some-good-apache-settings-to-use-with-wordpress

Comment: these are not threads, you can vote to close questions that don't fit the stacks scope if you see them

Comment: as a sidenote, while asking for advice on good _values_ would be off topic here since it's a discussion not a question, asking what the specific _correct value_ on the other hand _would_ be on topic since you can very clearly mark an answer as not just a useful reply, but the correct answer for all people with that question, even if that answer is "there isn't one it depends on the use case because..". Asking for general advice works best on a site structured as a discussion forum or a group which isn't how Stack Exchange is intended to work.