# Moved WordPress to New Server, Now Tries to Download a File

Tags: migration, server

Let me start by saying that I have moved dozens of websites from one server to another, without issue.

I recently moved a website and when the URL is visited, a file named "download" with no extension and only a 1KB file size downloads automatically. I backed up all files and downloaded the databases using four different methods, just to make sure: BackWPup, BackUpWordPress and manually by zipping the files & downloading the files via FTP.

The original website works perfectly on the original server.

I used the method I've always used when moving to a new server.

On the new server:

1. Create new DB, user and import database
2. Upload files and unzip
3. Edit wp-config.php with new DB name, user, password
4. Change the website URL using the functions.php method in the WordPress Codex, here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

I should also mention that I uploaded the site to three different servers (including a sub-domain on the original server), all with the same result.

In addition to the methods mentioned above, I tried the following things to try to troubleshoot:

1. Changed the "plugins" folder name to see if a plugin was causing
   the error
2. Changed the active theme folder name to see if the theme was causing the error
3. Changed WP_DEBUG to "true" in wp-conig.php - But the site never loads, so no errors are displayed.

Currently, the erroneous website is located at - http://cgdev.webworksplayground.com/

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I guess you haven't taken a look at the file that is served for downloading, if so you would have seen this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Which could have been easily identified as the content of the `index.php` file inside the root of your WordPress installation.

Regarding the cause(s) for this behavior, check if you are having the correct [file permissions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions), make sure your [htaccess](http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) file is correct. Besides that some other hosting related settings could be incorrect, see [Codex: Hosting WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hosting_WordPress) (not very informative though) or on here [What are best practices for configuring a server for Wordpress sites?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/4664/22534).

The above should get you started. I actually pretty much did have to make a - somewhat educated - guess about the reason(s), so inspect that deeper yourself, but I'm fairly certain the origins are in the general area that I addressed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The .htaccess had this added to the file - `# Use PHP54 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php` After removing it, all seems to work well.

Comment: My pleasure. Ok, thats a directive to use PHP 5.4 with Suhosin patch. Not sure why it won't work with it. I have used similar ones and never had a problem. Maybe ask your hosters support. @TravisPflanz

Comment: Hello @something , I am also facing the same issue. I checked my .htaccess file and found that my problem is similar to travis' problem. I also cleared that extra code from the file but when I enter to update permalinks the same code gets rewritten in the file.

Comment: @KeyurPatel It might be the server configuration, take al ook at the links in my answer for more information.

Comment: In my case clearing browser site data fixed the problem (In Chrome: settings > Site Settings > See all cookies and site data > delete applicable data). My issue came on the heels of a big php module installation.

Answer (score 5):

Simple steps

1 - Go to filemanager through cpanel or FTP

2 - Delete the .htaccess (make sure you have created a backup)

3 - Open your website and set the permalinks it will create a new .htaccess file .

4 - Enjoy!

I just deleted .htaccess file and it is working perfectly now :)

Comment: Deleting .htaccess works fine and regenerate new .htaccess automatically. Thanks

Comment: Yes. This technically works, but if the .htaccess file has anything else in it needed by the website, it will all be deleted.

Comment: basically recreating the .htaccess file works, but don't be fooled by Chrome caching.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply add the following line to .htaccess as well which allows variations of PHP just to be on the safe side.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Answer (score 1):

The mu-plugins adds a handler when you save the configuration
`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php` making the page being downloaded instead of processed.

If you just remove the line from your .htaccess (or delete the file), the line will come back at each settings save.

A better solution is to modify by ftp the file wp-content/mu-plugins/endurange-php-edge.php

Just comment (by adding "//" in front of the line) the line 20:
`// $this->hooks();`

Reference:
[htaccess problem after saving Settings](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285577/htaccess-problem-after-saving-settings)